# Make Swagger generation tool (Java classes generated by it) produce a custom JSON that the server is expecting

Tags: java, json, yaml, swagger, openapi

I'm calling a REST service with a *Swagger* generated *Java* client created by giving to it the `yaml` the server offers.

The `yaml` description given by the server for the service is :

```xml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: GeoServer Workspace
  description: A workspace is a grouping of data stores. Similar to a namespace, it is used to group data that is related in some way.
  contact:
    name: GeoServer
    email: 'geoserver-users@sourceforge.net'
    url: 'http://geoserver.org/comm/'
host: localhost:8080
basePath: /geoserver/rest
securityDefinitions:
  basic:
    type: basic
    description: HTTP Basic Authentication.
```

```xml
    post:
      operationId: postWorkspaces
      tags:
       - "Workspaces"
      summary: add a new workspace to GeoServer
      description: Adds a new workspace to the server
      security:
        - basic: []
      parameters:
        - name: workspaceBody
          description: The layer group body information to upload.
          in: body
          required: true          
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Workspace"
        - name: default
          in: query
          description: New workspace will be the used as the default. Allowed values are true or false,  The default value is false.
          required: false
          type: boolean
          default: false
      consumes: 
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - text/html
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
          schema:
            type: string
          headers:
            Location:
              description: URL where the newly created workspace can be found
              type: string
        401:
          description: Unable to add workspace as it already exists
```

```xml
definitions:
  Workspace:
    title: Workspace
    xml:
      name: workspace
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: name of the workspace
```

The *Swagger* generator creates simple classes from it, that are easy to use :

```java
Workspace workspace = new Workspace();
workspace.setName("test");
      
WorkspacesApi workspacesApi = new WorkspacesApi(apiClient()); // apiClient() : Authentication
String response = workspacesApi.postWorkspaces(workspace, true);
```

But the content JSON produced by it at call time makes the server failing :
`{ name: 'test' }`

I've discovered that the server expects a custom JSON :
`{workspace:{name:'test'}}`

And the *Swagger* generation won't respond to it's wishes : the `yaml` contains an `xml:` attribute that isn't a part of [Swagger schema 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject). The tool doesn't know what to do with it and ignore it.

```xml
definitions:
  Workspace:
    title: Workspace
    xml:
      name: workspace
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: name of the workspace
```

Do I have a way to enter in `yaml` some directives to create the custom JSON the server is looking for,
changing the `{ name: 'test' }` *Swagger* generation tool currently produces to `{workspace:{name:'test'}}` ?

Or do I have to add some plugin or ask the *Swagger* generation tool to override the classes generated (and how ?) to produce the target custom JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eidottermihi
By default, *Swagger* client accepts `JSON` content when it generates client classes.
If I change its `consumes:` declaration to `application/xml` only, at runtime, the client will complain that it has no handler for `xml` ready.

The problem is the one you said. Those who wrote the `yaml` file wrote it to have the `Swagger-UI` documentation generated, but they did it manually, and the `yaml` :

- isn't created automatically from the server classes,
- or it doesn't produce basic interfaces that the server implement.

It's a `yaml` written aside, a "*We believe our REST services are these ones.*" one. But with no guarantees, no proof...

Therefore, being unable to generate a correct client to call the REST services it pretends representing, it is strangely useless.

---

I have an answer to my question :

I'm able to generate the good JSON request for method `postWorkspaces` by changing it `$ref: "#/definitions/Workspace"` to a `$ref: "#/definitions/WorkspaceRequest"` I've declared :

```yaml
    post:
      operationId: postWorkspaces
      tags:
       - "Workspaces"
      summary: add a new workspace to GeoServer
      description: Adds a new workspace to the server
      security:
        - basic: []
      parameters:
        - name: workspaceBody
          description: The layer group body information to upload.
          in: body
          required: true          
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/WorkspaceRequest"
        - name: default
          in: query
          description: New workspace will be the used as the default. Allowed values are true or false,  The default value is false.
          required: false
          type: boolean
          default: false
      consumes: 
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      produces:
        - text/html
        - application/json
        - application/xml
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
          schema:
            type: string
          headers:
            Location:
              description: URL where the newly created workspace can be found
              type: string
        401:
          description: Unable to add workspace as it already exists
```

```yaml
definitions:
  Workspace:
    title: Workspace
    xml:
      name: workspace
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
        description: name of the workspace
      
  WorkspacesResponse:
    title: Workspaces
    type: object
    properties:
      workspaces:
        $ref: "#/definitions/WorkspaceResponse"
      
  WorkspaceRequest:
    title: Workspace Request
    type: object
    properties:
      workspace:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Workspace"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually "xml" is part of Swagger 2.0 (see https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#xml-modeling) and allows fine-grained control of the model when XML representation is used.

However you are using JSON and therefore the generated JSON payload by the generated Swagger Client is perfectly fine, and should be accepted by the Server.

This brings you to two options:

a) fix the server by accepting the payload (which is 100% compliant to the API specification)

b) Write a custom Client which sends the customized JSON payload to the server. The generated Swagger Client cannot be customized in this way.

Comment: I eventually found the solution to my problem, but you had the most helpful answer. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

The contents provided by the `toString()` method is some convenience feature for the developer. It does not necessarily produce valid JSON representation of the object. You should use a JSON serializer to serialize your JAVA object into a JSON string. This can for example be done with the help of the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.